# внесение изменений в гугл таблицу при ее создании

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Приветствую всех) Есть гугл таблица(шаблон) при определенном действии, скрипт делает ее копию в отдельную папку. Можно ли после создания копии сделать так чтоб скрипт поменял значения в ячейках первой строки например?

пытался сделать что-то типа того:

```
//Пытаемся внести изменения в созданую таблицу 
function myFunction1(FI) {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FI).getSheetByName("Лист1");    
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("проверка проверка");      
}

//копируем таблицу-шаблон в новую папку
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId).makeCopy();
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);
  
  var newFileId = DriveApp.getFileById(file);
  myFunction1(newFileId);
  
}
```

не работает :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Николай, после внесения правок получился следующий работоспособный вариант кода:

```
function myFunction1(FI) {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FI);    
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("проверка проверка");      
}

//копируем таблицу-шаблон в новую папку
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId).makeCopy(targetFolder);
  var newFileId = file.getId();
  myFunction1(newFileId);
}
```

Проверил, скрипт делает копию файла таблиц в отдельную папку и записывает данные в новую копию. Для меня осталось не ясным, почему Вы назвали функцию "moveFiles", я бы назвал "makeCopy". Но это не так важно.